# Selecting User Control for Data Template based on an Enum

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datatemplate

I am working on a WPF app and currently I have an `ItemsControl` bound up to my View Model `ObservableCollection` and I have a `DataTemplate` that uses a `UserControl` to render the items on `canvas`. Can you use multiple User Controls and then switch which one is used based on an `Enum`? Another way to look it is to either create a `Button` or a `TextBox` for the item in the `ObservableCollection` based on an `Enum`.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to change your `UserControl` based on `Enum` value, not on `ViewModel`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can select the data template for an item using a custom `DataTemplateSelector`. Assume we have the following:

```
public enum Kind
{
    Button, TextBox,
}

public class Data
{
    public Kind Kind { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Your data template selector might then look like this:

```
public class MyTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate ButtonTemplate { get; set; }

    public DataTemplate TextBoxTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        Data data = (Data)item;
        switch (data.Kind)
        {
            case Kind.Button:
                return ButtonTemplate;
            case Kind.TextBox:
                return TextBoxTemplate;
        }

        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }
}
```

In XAML, declare templates for all the cases you want to cover, in this case buttons and text boxes:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate" DataType="local:Data">
            <Button Content="{Binding Value}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="TextBoxTemplate" DataType="local:Data">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

Finally, have your `ItemsControl` create an instance of your custom template selector, initializing its two `DataTemplate`properties from the above data templates:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>
        <local:MyTemplateSelector
            ButtonTemplate="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}"
            TextBoxTemplate="{StaticResource TextBoxTemplate}"/>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>
    <ItemsControl.Items>
        <local:Data Kind="Button" Value="1. Button" />
        <local:Data Kind="TextBox" Value="2. TextBox" />
        <local:Data Kind="TextBox" Value="3. TextBox" />
        <local:Data Kind="Button" Value="4. Button" />
    </ItemsControl.Items>
</ItemsControl>
```

(In real life, set the `ItemsSource` instead of declaring the items inline, as I did.)

For completeness: To access your C# classes you need to set up the namespace, e.g.,

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF"
```

Comment: Fantastic response really helpful. I have got it working with UserControls which was my end goal thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible quick solution is to use Data Triggers:

```
<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Setter Property="Content"
                    Value="{StaticResource YourDefaultLayout}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding YourEnumVMProperty}"
                             Value="{x:Static local:YourEnum.EnumValue1}">
                    <Setter Property="Content"
                            Value="{StaticResource ContentForEnumValue1}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding YourEnumVMProperty}"
                             Value="{x:Static local:YourEnum.EnumValue2}">
                    <Setter Property="Content"
                            Value="{StaticResource ContentForEnumValue2}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```

You could also define the template of a whole control using a trigger setter.

I prefer this because there is no need to define all the DataTemplateSelector stuff etc.